# TabLayout added same list item

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I am trying to show registered users in list view in a fragment in a TabLayout but my problem is when I swipe from one tab layout to another and then come back to first one it copy  same users list and duplicately added  in that list and continuously goes on whenever I swipe to other tab layout. How can I fix this? 
UserListFragment.java

```
public class UserlistFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String TAG = "UserList";
ListView usersList;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseUser;
ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
private DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().getRoot();

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.userlist_fragment,container,false);

    mDatabaseUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

    usersList = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.usersList);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,list);
    usersList.setAdapter(adapter);
    usersList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String s = usersList.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
           /* Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Chat_Room.class);
            intent.putExtra("user_name",s);

            startActivity(intent);*/
        }
    });

    mDatabaseUser.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            /*list.add((String) dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));*/

            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

            // Check for null
            if (user == null) {
                // Log.e(TAG, "User data is null!");
                return;
            }
            list.add(user.username);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    return view;
}
```

}

MainActivity.java

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG ="MainActivity";
private SectionPageAdapter mSectionPageAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSectionPageAdapter = new SectionPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.container);

    setUpViewPager(mViewPager);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tab);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}

private void setUpViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
    SectionPageAdapter adapter = new SectionPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new UserlistFragment(), "Users");
    adapter.addFragment(new GroupFragment(), "Group");
    adapter.addFragment(new ProfileFragment(),"Profile");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_logout) {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SignActivity.class));
        finish();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

[Here is image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXnJw.jpg)

Comment: Can you include MainActivity code also?  Is there a ViewPager in your code?

Comment: How many tabs are there and are they all the same fragment... or does each tab contain a different type of fragment.  I have a possible solution but you don't explain enough in your question so I could be wasting my time.

Comment: Sorry for that...Yeah Sure I include that. Yes it have ViewPager and there is 3tabs and they are using 3 fragments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't heard back from you, so I will just try to answer anyway.

The problem is probably that your ChildEventListener is being created and re-added again and again without ever being removed.  This could be because the fragment is being re-created unnecessarily every time you swipe over to it (because it is not being kept in memory when swiped away) and/or because the mDatabaseUser object is somehow treated as static by Firebase and requires you to remove listeners even if the fragment containing the object is removed from memory.

There are two possible solutions.  You could use one or the other, or maybe both:

1) If you are using a ViewPager, then add this code:

```
int temp = // the number of tabs in your layout - 1
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(temp);
```

This will make sure the fragment stays in memory while it is off-screen and so when you swipe back to it, the onCreateView() method will NOT be executed again.

2) Make the following changes to your fragment:

-- Change the way you declare the listener so that you can reference it:

```
ChildEventListener derp = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        /*list.add((String) dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));*/

            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

            // Check for null
            if (user == null) {
                // Log.e(TAG, "User data is null!");
                return;
            }
            list.add(user.username);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };

mDatabaseUser.addChildEventListener(derp);
```

-- Add the following method:

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mDatabaseUser.removeEventListener(derp);
}
```

This will ensure that if for whatever reason the fragment is removed from memory, that the listener will be removed.

Hope that helps.